Why do I lose accuracy as precision and scale increase with decimal types in SQL Server?
I made this script where I'm dividing 1 / 7 and increasing the precision and scale by 1 each time.
Despite the specified scale values it starts off giving an answer with 6 digits after the decimal, 0.142857, reaches maximum accuracy at precision 13, scale 12 with 0.1428571428571428571428571 and then starts falling off again, 1 digit at a time until by precision 32 and scale 31 it's fallen back to 0.142857.
The precision and scale I'd like to use is 34 and 20, respectively, as I have to multiply very large numbers by very small ones.
What's going on here?
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(2,1), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(2,1), 7.0), 2 AS P, 1 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2), 7.0), 3 AS P, 2 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,3), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,3), 7.0), 4 AS P, 3 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,4), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,4), 7.0), 5 AS P, 4 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,5), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,5), 7.0), 6 AS P, 5 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,6), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(7,6), 7.0), 7 AS P, 6 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,7), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,7), 7.0), 8 AS P, 7 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,8), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,8), 7.0), 9 AS P, 8 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,9), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,9), 7.0), 10 AS P, 9 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,10), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(11,10), 7.0), 11 AS P, 10 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,11), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,11), 7.0), 12 AS P, 11 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(13,12), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(13,12), 7.0), 13 AS P, 12 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(14,13), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(14,13), 7.0), 14 AS P, 13 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,14), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(15,14), 7.0), 15 AS P, 14 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,15), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(16,15), 7.0), 16 AS P, 15 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(17,16), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(17,16), 7.0), 17 AS P, 16 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,17), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,17), 7.0), 18 AS P, 17 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,18), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,18), 7.0), 19 AS P, 18 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,19), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,19), 7.0), 20 AS P, 19 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(21,20), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(21,20), 7.0), 21 AS P, 20 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(22,21), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(22,21), 7.0), 22 AS P, 21 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(23,22), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(23,22), 7.0), 23 AS P, 22 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(24,23), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(24,23), 7.0), 24 AS P, 23 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(25,24), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(25,24), 7.0), 25 AS P, 24 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(26,25), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(26,25), 7.0), 26 AS P, 25 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(27,26), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(27,26), 7.0), 27 AS P, 26 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(28,27), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(28,27), 7.0), 28 AS P, 27 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(29,28), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(29,28), 7.0), 29 AS P, 28 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,29), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(30,29), 7.0), 30 AS P, 29 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(31,30), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(31,30), 7.0), 31 AS P, 30 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(32,31), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(32,31), 7.0), 32 AS P, 31 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(33,32), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(33,32), 7.0), 33 AS P, 32 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(34,33), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(34,33), 7.0), 34 AS P, 33 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(35,34), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(35,34), 7.0), 35 AS P, 34 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(36,35), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(36,35), 7.0), 36 AS P, 35 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(37,36), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(37,36), 7.0), 37 AS P, 36 AS S
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,37), 1.0) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,37), 7.0), 38 AS P, 37 AS S


https://web.archive.org/web/20160108174802/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/03/29/564110.aspx
